# how do we filter items on observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

model looks like below

```
export class FileQueueObject {
    public file: any; // used any because selected file contain.
    public status: FileQueueStatus = FileQueueStatus.Pending;
    public progress = 0;
    public request: Subscription = null;
    public response: HttpResponse<object> | HttpErrorResponse = null;

    constructor(file: any) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    // statuses
    public isPending = () => this.status === FileQueueStatus.Pending;
    public isSuccess = () => this.status === FileQueueStatus.Success;
    public isError = () => this.status === FileQueueStatus.Error;
    public inProgress = () => this.status === FileQueueStatus.Progress;
    public isUploadable = () => this.status === FileQueueStatus.Pending || this.status === FileQueueStatus.Error;
}
```

TS

```
queue: Observable<FileQueueObject[]>;
```

html looks like below

3 Question :

what i want to achieve is,

1 - item who is `inProgress === true` put in different section.

```
<span>Uploading <span>
        <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of queue | async"> 
            <div>{{ item.file?.name }}</div>
            <div>{{ item.file?.size }}</div>
            <a *ngIf="item.inProgress()">Cancel</a>
        </li>
        <ul>
```

2 -item who is in `isSuccess===true` put in different section.

```
<span>Uploaded <span>
        <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of queue | async"> 
            <div>{{ item.file?.name }}</div>
            <div>{{ item.file?.size }}</div>
            <a *ngIf="!item.inProgress()">Remove</a>
        </li>
        <ul>
```

header should be visible if only 1 item is in that category.

3 - is it possible to have this by write only 1 html, something like below?

```
<span *ngIf="">Uploading <span>  
<span *ngIf="">Uploaded <span>
            <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of queue | async"> 
                <div>{{ item.file?.name }}</div>
                <div>{{ item.file?.size }}</div>
                <a *ngIf="item.inProgress()">Cancel</a>
                <a *ngIf="!item.inProgress()">Remove</a>
            </li>
            <ul>
```

what do you suggest, if i want to display item as uploading and uploaded, uploading will have cancel button, and uploaded will have remove button

what i tried is

```
    getInProgressItem(): any {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
    // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
    const a = this.queue.pipe(filter((result, id): any => {
      return result.filter((x) => x.inProgress() === true);
    }));
    return a;
  }

  getSuccussItem(): any {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
    // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused
    const b = this.queue.pipe(filter((result, id): any => {
      return result.filter((x) => x.isSuccess() === true);
    }));
    return b;
  }
<span *ngIf="(getInProgressItem().length > 0 | async)"
          class="c-fileupload__indicator">Uploading</span>
    <span *ngIf="(getSuccussItem().length > 0 | async)"
          class="c-fileupload__indicator">Uploaded</span>
```

and it is not working for me

Comment: Please add only relevant tags

Comment: Are you subscribing to anything.  do you use Subjects etc?  how do you push/change state

Comment: "what i tried is", "will it work"... Well, if you tried it, you tell us: does it work?

Comment: @jcuypers - i'm using async pipe in angular , i guess, it should do job as subscribing , no just declared as queue: Observable<FileQueueObject[]>;

Comment: @LazarLjubenović - no it is not working for me!

Comment: i am still wondering how can we do filter on observable and bind to angular ngIf or ngfor

Comment: Is `<div *ngIf="(someStreamOfItems | async).length > 0">there are some items</div>` the thing you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Andrei - yes ( question 3 i am trying from upper SO question )

Comment: @Andrei =>> <span *ngIf="(getInProgressItem() | async).length > 0"
         >Uploading</span>
    <span *ngIf="(getSuccussItem() | async).length > 0)"
          >Uploaded</span>

Comment: correct me, please, if I'm wrong: You are trying to make 2 pretty simmilar lists on ui and show your items either in first or in the second of them

Comment: @Andrei - correct, basically for file upload, i need to show it is either inprogress or in success,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the appropriate solutions is to split your queue observable into 2 observables like this:

```
queueSuccessfulItems = this.queue.pipe(map(items => items.filter(item => item.isSuccess())))
queueInProgressItems = this.queue.pipe(map(items => items.filter(item => item.inProgress())))
```

and then use it like

```
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="item">
   <div>{{ item.file?.name }}</div>
   <div>{{ item.file?.size }}</div
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngIf="queueInProgressItems | async as inProgressItems">
  <div *ngIf="inProgressItems.length"> <!-- here we have an array, not a stream -->
   <span>Uploading <span>
    <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of inProgressItems"> 
       <ng-container 
        *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate;context:{item: item}">
       </ng-container>
       <a>Cancel</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="queueSuccessfulItems | async as successfulItems">
  <div *ngIf="successfulItems.length">
   <span>Uploaded <span>
    <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of successfulItems"> 
       <ng-container 
        *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate;context:{item: item}">
       </ng-container>
       <a>Remove</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: you can actually unite this whole list html into 1 component/template and use different buttons and spans with the help of `ngIf`

Comment: can we use <div> as main ng-container ? and put all things inside {{ item.file?.size }} in <div> ? - just curious why we need to use main ng container?

Comment: ng-container will not be rendered in the result html. I made it to separate `| async as` and `*ngIf=items.lnegth"` logic because angular doesnt support reference and condition like `*ngIf="(itemsStream | async as items).length"` in one place for some reason

Comment: i will create stackblitz for this solution

Comment: please check out this solution, the answer is not working for me = >https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-file-upload-queue-7mtdbb?file=app%2Ffile-uploader.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-file-upload-queue-jyjrgt?file=app/file-uploader.component.html I edited it a bit. if you want to render 2 lists, you have to write them twice, or use template/component to reuse that template. one more thing I changed is creating of new streams is done in ngOnInit rather than in a method. those methods would be called on every change detection and async pipe would resubscribe to these new observables too often

Comment: it is working - accepted as answer ( Side Question -  item.remove() & item.Cancel() event will work ? ) because now it will be on different observable.

Comment: most of javascript is available in these expressions. So item.remove(); item.Cancel() is more javascripty, even thou your version is working